# Translating a VBA function into R

Tags: r, vba, probability-theory

I am attempting to translate the function DISCRINV() which is an excel function available in the simtools excel add-in that was created by Roger Myerson into an R function. I believe i am close, but am having difficulty understanding the looping syntax of VBA.

**The VBA code for this function is as follows:**

```
Function DISCRINV(ByVal randprob As Double, values As Object, probabilities As Object)
On Error GoTo 63
Dim i As Integer, cumv As Double, cel As Object
If values.Count <> probabilities.Count Then GoTo 63
For Each cel In probabilities
 i = i + 1
 cumv = cumv + cel.Value
 If randprob < cumv Then
 DISCRINV = values.Cells(i).Value
 Exit Function
 End If
Next cel
If randprob < cumv + 0.001 Then
 DISCRINV = values.Cells(i).Value
 Exit Function
End If
63 DISCRINV = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

**Attempting to translate this directly from the VBA code i have come up with this (Not Correct):**

```
DISCRINV <- function(R,V,P){
 if(length(V) != length(P)){
   print("ERROR NUMBER OF VALUES DOES NOT EQUAL NUMBER OF PROBABILITIES")
 } else{
   for (i in 1:length(P)){
     cumv=cumv+P[i]
     if (R < cumv){
       DISCY1 = V[i]
       return(DISCY1)
       }

   print(cumv)

 if (R < cumv +0.001){

   DISCY2 = V[i]

   return(DISCY2)
 }
   }
 }
}
```

**Attempting to translate this through my understanding of what it is doing i have come up with this:**

```
DISCRINV <- function(x,values,probabilities){
  require(FSA)
  precumsum <- pcumsum(probabilities)
  middle <- c()
  for (i in 1:(length(values)-2)){
    if (precumsum[i+1] <= x & x < precumsum[i+2]){
      middle[i] <- values[i+1]}
    else{
      middle[i] <- 0
    }
  }

  firstrow <- ifelse(x < precumsum[2], values[1], 0)
  lastrow <- ifelse(precumsum[length(precumsum)] <= x , values[length(precumsum)] , 0)
  Gvector <- c(firstrow,middle,lastrow)
  print(firstrow)
  print(middle)
  print(lastrow)
  print(Gvector)
  simulatedvalue <-  sum(Gvector)

  return(simulatedvalue)
}
```

The latter option works 99% of the time, but not when the first function parameter is over 0.5, the second parameter is a vector of values c(1000,2000) and the third parameter is a vector (0.5,0.5). The case of the latter option not working 100% of the time is what has led me to try to translate the function directly. Could someone please give some insight into where my translation is going wrong?

**Additionally a description of the function is as follows:**

DISCRINV(randprob, values, probabilities) returns inverse cumulative values for a discrete random variable. When the first parameter is a RAND, DISCRINV returns a discrete random variable with possible values and corresponding probabilities in the given ranges.

Thank you in advance for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is interested, i was able to successfully translate this VBA script using this code

```
    DISCRINV <- function(x,values,probabilities){
    require(FSA)
    precumsum <- pcumsum(probabilities)
    middle <- c()
    if(length(values <3 )){

    if(x<0.5){
    middle1 <- values[1]
    return(middle1)
    } else{
    middle2 <- values[2]
    return(middle2)
    }
    }
    else{
    for (i in 1:(length(values)-2)){
    if (precumsum[i+1] <= x & x < precumsum[i+2]){
    middle[i] <- values[i+1]}
    else{
    middle[i] <- 0
    }
    }
    firstrow <- ifelse(x < precumsum[2], values[1], 0)
    lastrow <- ifelse(precumsum[length(precumsum)] <= x , values[length(precumsum)] , 0)
    Gvector <- c(firstrow,middle,lastrow)
    print(firstrow)
    print(middle)
    print(lastrow)
    print(Gvector)
    simulatedvalue <-  sum(Gvector)

    return(simulatedvalue)
    }
    }
```